# Normalisation of Relational Databases

Tags: database, normalization, database-normalization, functional-dependencies

I'm going through a mark scheme of a Normalisation exam question. It gives the table shown in the image attached and asks the pupil to normalise to 3rd normal form. Below the table in the image is the mark scheme for that question.

Does anyone know why in 2NF the Dept ID is left in the Team-Employee table? It's removed later but I'm at a loss as to why it's kept there at that point?

[image: Diagram with 1NF data and outline schemas]

Comment: On the whole, it is best to enter what's in the image as text.

Comment: You haven't included enough information. What are the functional dependencies? Eg does a given employeeid only appear with one deptid?

Comment: Do you have a reference for the source of this example?

Answer (score 2):

Because in 1NF

- Contains only atomic values
- There are no repeating groups

2nd Normal form

- All non-key attributes are fully functional dependent on the primary key

3rd normal form

- There is no transitive functional dependency that it is in 3NF.

DeptID is dependant on which employee you're looking at.  thus it is in 1st and 2nd normal form.  It's not until   3rd normal form that the one to many relationship between employee and departmentID must be extracted.

In your case Dept name is tied to DeptID and DeptID is tied to Employee thus deptName has a transitive functional dependency.  In other words.  The table has a one to many relationship within it self; which is not allowed in 3rd normal form.  But it fits within 2NF because department is tied to employee directly and is not a many-to-many that would have needed to be resolved in 1st Normal form.

Comment: TEAM-EMPLOYEE-2 has a partial FD determining DeptID so it can't be in 2NF. (See my answer.) PS That FD means employee:dept is many:1.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't included enough information. We can see some places where there are not functional dependencies, but we don't know whether the cases that are consistent with functional dependencies actually are.

But assuming that DeptID is functionally determined by {EmployeeID} (ie a given EmployeeID only appears with one DeptID) (which is the case according to EMPLOYEE having {EmployeeID} as candidate key determining DeptID), TEAM-EMPLOYEE-2 having DeptID with candidate key {TeamID,EmployeeID} would not be in 2NF since DeptID is functionally dependent on a proper subset ({EmployeeID}) of a candidate key (ie it is non fully functionally dependent on it). Yet it appears under 2NF in your (alleged) solution.

So probably it's a typo. (Also because it's just strange to have decomposed leaving it in both components.)